# Postgres not logging all queries, despite logging the duration

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to get my postgresql 9.3 server to log all sql that runs longer than 1 second.  I have set:

```
log_min_duration=1s
log_statement='mod'
log_duration=off
```

for most queries, the logging is working correclty, but some statements, such as "CREATE TABLE AS" or "INSERT" are not logging the statement.  The log the duration, but not the complete sql.

Has anyone else seen this type of issue before, or know why postgres may not be logging the sql?  (possibly a transaction block?) Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct parameter is `log_min_duration_statement` and not `log_min_duration`.

And this note, from [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-logging.html),

> Note: When using this option together with log_statement, the text of
>   statements that are logged because of log_statement will not be
>   repeated in the duration log message. If you are not using syslog, it
>   is recommended that you log the PID or session ID using
>   log_line_prefix so that you can link the statement message to the
>   later duration message using the process ID or session ID.

consider is a good explanation for problem.